# Extended Validation vs "Standard" TSA/TimeStamping Certificate

Tags: timestamp, digital-signature

I have seen binaries signed with EV TSA/TimeStamping Certificates, but also with "Standard" TSA/TimeStamping Certificates.

In particular, I have seen it with Certum (CN=Certum EV TSA SHA2). What is the difference between EV and "Standard", when it comes to the TimeStamp?